# Azure DevOps Release Pipelines - Using env parms with a period . in

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-powershell

I am finding using AZDO Release pipeline variables maddening in Powershell steps.

I am running an Azure PowerShell step to return a primary key value. It is 2 lines…

```js
$primarykey = (Get-AzRelayKey -ResourceGroupName ${env:az-resourcegroupname} -Namespace ${env:az-relaynamespace} -HybridConnection ${env:serviceBus.primaryRelay.ConnectionName} -Name ${env:serviceBus.primaryRelay.KeyName} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty PrimaryKey)

Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=serviceBus.primaryRelay.Key]$primarykey"
```

In my pipeline I have a mix of variable names, some I have complete control over (the **az-** prefixed ones) and others I don’t (the ones starting **serviceBus.**)

The reason I have no control over the latter is that they are used for a later File Transform step that navigates an appsettings.json file to find/replace values, and its unable to be changed (for example serviceBus.primaryRelay.ConnectionName is a value that is changed in the JSON and the file transform step specifies to navigate the JSON structure, it has to be separated with a period . )

When this script runs it always complains about the **-HybridConnection** value being empty. This is because the variable has a period in it.

I’ve tried everything I can think of to retrieve that value in the code.

Are they suggesting here that a variable with a period isn’t workable in Powershell in AZDO release pipelines? I’m completely lost.

[image] [image]

Comment: Does it work locally? it's the correct way to use ${env:serviceBus.primaryRelay.ConnectionName} to call a env variable which contains "." . And also make sure the value is not empty in the source.

Comment: Yes and Yes. I've added some screenshots above

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer by looking under the Release Pipelines "Initialize Job" log. It appears to substitute the period . with a dash -

The log revealed this...

**[SERVICEBUS_PRIMARYRELAY_CONNECTIONNAME] --> [dev-sbrelay]**